# Need Sql query to get time difference based on status

Tags: sql, sql-server

[below is the sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWTVb.png)

I need total Time when **Ebstatus** and **dgstatus** is **ON** and till next **DgStatus** is **OFF**.

For example if we consider below data:

```
Ebstatus  | dgstatus | ReadTime
  ON  |  ON  | 16/07/2017  3:00:00  
  ON  | ON   | 16/07/2017  4:00:00  
  ON  | OFF  | 16/07/2017  5:00:00
  ON  | OFF  | 16/07/2017  6:00:00
  ON  | ON   | 16/07/2017  7:00:00
  ON  | OFF  | 16/07/2017  9:00:00
```

Here total ON time is 2 hours (3 to 4 - > 1 hour and it still ON until 5, so total ON time is 2 hours) and both status again ON at 7 and **Dgstatus** OFF at 9,so here total ON time is 2hours.

Finally Total ON time is 4 hours

Can somebody give Query for SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Tag your question with the version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @JFPicard ,No actually i am new to sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could reduce to one row per `ON` and `OFF`, then aggregation would solve the problem.  You can do that using the difference of row numbers method:

```
select ebstatus, dgstatus,
       min(readtime) as min_rt, max(readtime) as max_rt
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ebstatus order by readtime) as seqnum_d,
             row_number() over (partition by ebstatus, dgstatus partition by readtime) as seqnum_sd
      from t
     ) t
group by ebstatus, dgstatus, (seqnum_sd - seqnum_d);
```

From this, you can get the totals:

```
select sum(datediff(hour, min_rt, next_min_rt)) as on_hours
from (select ebstatus, dgstatus,
             min(readtime) as min_rt, max(readtime) as max_rt,
             lead(min(readtime)) over (partition by ebstatus, dgstatus order by min(readtime)) as next_min_rt
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by ebstatus order by readtime) as seqnum_d,
                   row_number() over (partition by ebstatus, dgstatus partition by readtime) as seqnum_sd
            from t
           ) t
      group by ebstatus, dgstatus, (seqnum_sd - seqnum_d)
     ) t
where dgstatus = 'ON' and ebstatus = 'ON';
```

Comment: Thank you very much.How to achieve same thing in 2008 server?

Answer (score 0):

LAG lets you check the previous row so you can check for a change in dgstatus v alue

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
DECLARE @Mytable table (Ebstatus varchar(2), dgstatus varchar(3), ReadTime smalldatetime)

INSERT @Mytable VALUES
  ('ON', 'ON ', '16/07/2017  3:00:00'),  
  ('ON', 'ON ', '16/07/2017  4:00:00'),  
  ('ON', 'OFF', '16/07/2017  5:00:00'),
  ('ON', 'OFF', '16/07/2017  6:00:00'),
  ('ON', 'ON ', '16/07/2017  7:00:00'),
  ('ON', 'OFF', '16/07/2017  9:00:00');

SELECT 
    SUM(Hours)
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        Hours = CASE 
                    WHEN 
                       Ebstatus = 'ON' AND 
                       dgstatus = 'OFF' AND --may be needed to ensure we only count OFF rows
                       LAG(dgstatus) OVER (ORDER BY ReadTime) <> dgstatus 
                    THEN
                       DATEDIFF(HOUR, LAG(ReadTime) OVER (ORDER BY ReadTime), ReadTime)
                  ELSE 0 END
    FROM 
        @Mytable
    ) X;
```